# How to use SSIS to read from ActiveMQ Queue?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, activemq-classic

I'm a newbie to SSIS, my current workplace requires that we use SSIS to read from ActiveMQ (hosted service by Amazon) and populate certain SQLServer DB tables.

I've used NiFi to some extent in the past but not SSIS and SSIS 2016 doesn't have an ActiveMQ connectior

 After googling around, learnt SSIS-ActiveMQ connection can be achieved using Script component of SSIS.

I can do bit of .net / C# scripting if need be, please advise if theres a template project out there or a how-to-guide to write the **Script** using **NMS .net libraries**. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of reading through AMQ documentation, I could do this myself. 
Below is the complete code which currently works but obviously needs bit of TLC, all suggestions welcome.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Apache.NMS;
using Serilog;

namespace AMQ_ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string AMQ_URI = "activemq:ssl://abc.net";
        private const string AMQ_Queue = "test";
        private const string AMQ_User = "userId";
        private const string AMQ_Pwd = "password";       

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console(
                    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                    )
                .WriteTo.File("AMQ_SSIS_Connector.log"
                    , rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day
                    , outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                    , retainedFileCountLimit:30
                    )
                .CreateLogger();
            try
            {   Log.Information("#### BEGIN #####");
                IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(new Uri(AMQ_URI));

                IConnection Q_connection = factory.CreateConnection(AMQ_User, AMQ_Pwd);
                ISession Q_session = Q_connection.CreateSession();

                Log.Debug("Attempting to connect to Queue {Queue}", AMQ_Queue);
                Q_connection.Start();
                IDestination destination = Q_session.GetQueue(AMQ_Queue);
                IMessageConsumer consumer = Q_session.CreateConsumer(destination);

                IMessage message;
                while (true)
                {
                    Log.Information("______________________________");
                    Log.Information("Awaiting new message...");
                    message = consumer.Receive();
                    if (message != null)
                    {
                        ITextMessage textMessage = message as ITextMessage;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textMessage.Text))
                        {
                            Log.Information("Reading message with ID : " + textMessage.NMSMessageId);
                            WriteToDB(textMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }               
            //ShutDown(Q_session, Q_connection);
        }

        public static void WriteToDB(ITextMessage msg)
        {
            try
            {
                const string SQL_Datasource = "(localdb)\\LocalDBv14";
                const string SQL_InitialCatalog = "Customer";
                const string SQL_User = "";  
                const string SQL_User_Pwd = ""; 
                const string SQL_TargetTable = "TableA";
                const string SQL_Schema = "dbo";

                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                builder.DataSource = SQL_Datasource;                
                builder.InitialCatalog = SQL_InitialCatalog;
                builder.IntegratedSecurity = true; // Disable for Named SQLServer A/c

                StringBuilder sb_SQL = new StringBuilder();
                sb_SQL.Append("INSERT INTO ");
                sb_SQL.Append("[");
                sb_SQL.Append(SQL_Schema);//
                sb_SQL.Append("].[");
                sb_SQL.Append(SQL_TargetTable);//
                sb_SQL.Append("] (");

                sb_SQL.Append("[" + "MessageID" + "]");//Fields
                sb_SQL.Append(",[" + "Message" + "]");//Fields

                sb_SQL.Append(",[" + "AMQ_URI" + "]");//Fields
                sb_SQL.Append(",[" + "AMQ_Queue" + "]");//Fields
                sb_SQL.Append(",[" + "AMQ_Type" + "]");//Fields
                sb_SQL.Append(",[" + "AMQ_Timestamp" + "]");//Fields
                sb_SQL.Append(",[" + "RECORD_INSERTED_AT" + "]");//Fields
                sb_SQL.Append(",[" + "RECORD_INSERTED_BY" + "]");//Fields

                sb_SQL.Append(") VALUES (");

                sb_SQL.Append("'" + msg.NMSMessageId + "'");//Data
                sb_SQL.Append(",'" + msg.Text + "'");//Data

                sb_SQL.Append(",'" + AMQ_URI + "'");//Data
                sb_SQL.Append(",'" + msg.NMSDestination.ToString() + "'");//Data
                sb_SQL.Append(",'" + msg.NMSType + "'");//Data
                sb_SQL.Append("," + msg.NMSTimestamp );//Data

                sb_SQL.Append("," + "getdate()" + "");//Data
                sb_SQL.Append(",'" + "SSIS_User" + "'");//Data
                sb_SQL.Append(")");

                // Connect to SQL
                Log.Information("Connecting to SQL Server...{Server}", SQL_Datasource);
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    int ret_rows = 0;
                    Log.Information("Opening DB Connection...{Connection}", SQL_Datasource+"."+SQL_InitialCatalog+"."+SQL_Schema);
                    connection.Open();

                    Log.Information("Inserting data into...{Table}", SQL_TargetTable);
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sb_SQL.ToString(), connection))

                    ret_rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (ret_rows > 0)
                    {                        
                        Log.Information("Data committed to DB successfully, Inserted {records} records." , ret_rows);
                        //DequeueMessage(msg);
                    }
                    else {

                        Log.Fatal("Data commit to DB Failed.");
                    }

                    Log.Information("Closing DB connection...");
                    connection.Close();
                    Log.Information("DB Connection closed.");
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Log.Error(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void DequeueMessage(IMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                message.Acknowledge();
                Log.Information("Message with ID {msg} de-queued from AMQ.", message.NMSMessageId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }

        }

        private static void ShutDown(ISession session, IConnection connection)
        {
            Log.Information("Ending AMQ Session");
            session.Close();

            Log.Information("Closing AMQ Connection");
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```